# How to stop using iCloud Music Library on Mac and iOS?

Tags: itunes, icloud, apple-music

While trying Apple Music this summer, I must have switched on the *iCloud Music Library* functions. I finished using Apple Music, and **I would like to get rid of that iCloud Music Library**.

I'd like to return to...

- having my music on my Mac
- syncing selected playlists, albums and artists to my iOS devices
- NOT having my music on iCloud at all

I am on OS X 10.11.1 and iTunes 12.3.1 on the Mac and iOS 9.2 on my iPhone and iPad.

How can I accomplish this?

**Update:**
of course, I have googled this, resulting either in

- partial (iOS only),
- outdated (iTunes 12.x seems to have had a switch in Preferences that 12.3. doesn't have) or
- immensely unattractive (restore iTunes Library from TimeMachine - I would have to go back to June, it is November now...)

solutions.

On my **iPhone**, I was able to have it show only music that is stored locally on my iPhone.

On my **Mac** in iTunes, it tells me to log into iCloud regularly. Often, I see duplicate entries in my playlists. When I rip a CD, it will get uploaded to iCloud. Sometimes, I cannot see my music library but the spinning circle with the message "connecting to iCloud".

I don't like this at all, and frankly, I'm quite upset about Apple's policy...

Comment: This sounds a lot like iCloud Photo Library - which was horrible. At least that was possible (with a lot of work) to disable completely and for good. This may be a rhetorical question but is there any chance that you purchased the music through iTunes?

Comment: @bassplayer7 I purchased lots of music through iTunes, since the very beginning of iTunes. Don't want to miss that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I searched and found a few articles and threads that dealt with similar issues. It looks like the option to turn off iCloud Music Library for both the iPhone and Mac has been hidden in iTunes >> Preferences >> General. Uncheck the box next to "Show Apple Music". After unchecking the box you are given a message about iCloud Music Library. Next, you will want to reset your iCloud Music Library settings in iTunes. Go to Store >> View Account, enter your Apple ID and Password, then click "View Account". Once the Account Information page loads, scroll to the bottom and click the "Reset" button for the option to reset iCloud Music Library. You will be asked to delete all of the music and libraries stored in iCloud Music Library. Check "I Understand", and click "Reset". After you confirm and click "Reset Now", quit iTunes. Links to the full articles:

- https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204964
- [How to prevent iTunes 12.2 from automatically uploading sound tracks to iCloud Music Library?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193896/how-to-prevent-itunes-12-2-from-automatically-uploading-sound-tracks-to-icloud-m)

Now, verify that the settings are correct on your iPhone. Go to Settings >> Music. Under Apple Music, slide OFF "Show Apple Music". Finally, Power off your iPhone for 30 seconds and then power back on. If the music library on your iPhone still contains music from iCloud, tap the Music app, tap Library at the top, tap the red text (will read either: Artists, Albums, Songs, Music Videos, Genres, Composers, or Compilations), then slide ON "Only Offline Music".

Following these steps should provide the results you are trying to obtain. It deletes any music and libraries from iCloud but leaves your original library in tact, allowing you to continue syncing selected playlist, albums, and artists to your iOS devices.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer! Unfortunately, I neither get a message about iCloud Music Library when disabling "show Apple Music" in iTunes-settings, nor is there a button within the account page to reset iCloud Music Library. Might be that these settings have been changed after your reply, I only got to try it today.

Comment: I don't see this option either.  (I'm using iTunes 12.4.)

Comment: why is this answer accepted? Problem setter states he has 12.3, and this answer is for 12.2 it CANNOT work for 12.3 (nor 12.4).

Answer (score -1):

iTunes 12.3:  View >> Hide iCloud Music Purchases

Comment: Seems like that only hides it, not actually disables it.